# How to fix the backlight cable into its place?

Tags: thinkpad, backlight, tape

I took apart my laptop and found out that if I push the cable connector down with my fingers it works fine. I tried to twist the screws as tightly as I can (without ruining them) but as I move the screen forward and backward it becomes dim from time to time.

Can I use tape to fix the cable in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is common to use tape to keep the cables from moving. The tape rather then the connector takes most of the tension.

Comment: Is any kind of tape okay? I don't think I can fix the cable in place since it's connected to the screen. I can only tape down the connector.

Comment: @Anh Normally, stiffer tape is used, I believe. Kapton tape is what usually comes from the manufacturer. But other tapes should do fine - try to get some without adhesive that melts all over the place.